# Find a date older than 15 days in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

i need to show compare a delivery date if it is 15 days over and also show a track_track_status=0 as default.when i do this it throws the error

Error
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''delivery_date' + INTERVAL 15 DAY < NOW()' in 'where clause

```
$secondstatus = DB::table('registrations')
            ->join('ssi_tracks', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'ssi_tracks.registration_id')
            ->select('ssi_tracks.ssi_track_id', 'address', 'model', 'chassis', 'delivery_date','ssi_tracks.track_second_status')
            ->where([["ssi_tracks.track_second_status", "=", 0]])
             ->orWhereRaw('registrations.delivery_date + INTERVAL 15 DAY <= NOW()')

            ->get();
```

Comment: You need a raw query, since you're using an SQL function. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Now i have done like this now it is showing everything and i changed the date but only shows everything @JoelHinz

Comment: Can you write the query without the framework? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) with laravel [`orWhere`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orWhere) instead

```
->orWhere( 'delivery_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(15))
```

Comment: This is the more elegant solution.

Comment: Is `Carbon` included with `Laravel`?

Comment: but it doesn't return nothing i change to the date and but nothing showing in the datatable @C2486

Comment: No error showing for checking i tried comment ->where([["ssi_tracks.track_second_status", "=", 0]]) this part and changed my date but nothing showing @C2486

Comment: @Abhijith : the code you shared retuned nothing. can you check `return dd($secondstatus)`;  and share what you get?

Comment: doesn't "older than 15 days" mean `<=` in the comparison?

Comment: @apokryfos : yes you are right it should `<=` to get previous data.

Comment: Which `Carbon` should I use `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` or `Carbon\Carbon`?

Comment: @Abhijith : Check you query after changing `>=` to `<=`

Comment: @SandOfVega : you can use `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Answer (score 0):

use raw query as below:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

->orWhere(DB::raw(registrations.delivery_date + INTERVAL 15 DAY, "<=", $now))
```

check it and response here if it returns any error.

Comment: You missed two things 1st using `or` in where condition and 2nd `=` in query for date comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$secondstatus = DB::table('registrations')
            ->join('ssi_tracks', 'registrations.registration_id', '=', 'ssi_tracks.registration_id')
            ->select('ssi_tracks.ssi_track_id', 'address', 'model', 'chassis', 'delivery_date','ssi_tracks.track_second_status')
            ->where([["ssi_tracks.track_second_status", "=", 0]])
             ->orWhere('registrations.delivery_date', '<=', \DB::raw("NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAYS")))    
            ->get();
```

Problem being that the query builder will alias the table name and will but will not alias it if it's within a `whereRaw`